# CSS / JQuery / Javascript loading icon only works in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a very simple loading icon, the div is full screen and the image is just a gif:

```
<div id="loading" class="a">
  <img id="loading-gif" src="img/general/712.gif" width="50px" height="50px" class="b" />
</div>
```

Here are the styles:

```
.a {
  display: none; 
  position: absolute; 
  z-index: 9999; 
  top: 0px; 
  left: 0px; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}

.b {
  display: block; 
  position: absolute; 
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

When I want to display it, I do so like this:

```
var hCenter = (Math.floor(window.innerWidth/2)) - 25;
var vTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
var vCenter = (Math.floor(window.innerHeight/2)) - 25;  

$("#loading-gif").css({top: vTop + vCenter, left: hCenter});
$("#loading").show();
```

And to hide:

```
$("#loading").hide();
```

This works fine in firefox but doesn't seem to work in Chrome or on my iPhone.  I can't see an error anywhere - any idea why some browsers don't like it?

Thanks

Comment: `.show()` will not hide it!

Comment: I wonder if this code hiding it ??? `$("#loading").show();`

Comment: `$("#loading").hide();` is the one to hide

Comment: You forgot to mention unit ! `+'px'` => `$("#loading-gif").css({top: (vTop + vCenter)+'px', left: hCenter+'px'});
`

Comment: $("#loading").toggle();

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
.hidden {
display:none;
}
```

Then you can add and remove the class to show and hide it.

To hide:

```
$("#loading").addClass("hidden");
```

To show:

```
$("#loading").removeClass("hidden");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

**JavaScript**

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#status').delay(100).fadeOut('slow');
    $('#preloader').delay(200).fadeOut('slow');
    $('body').delay(200).css({'overflow':'visible'});
});
```

**CSS**

```
/* cover complete screen */
#preloader {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#FFF; 
    z-index:9999; /* makes sure it stays on top */
    -webkit-transition:none;
            transition:none;}

/* preloader container at the middle */
#status {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%; /* centers the loading animation horizontally one the screen */
    top:50%; /* centers the loading animation vertically one the screen */
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    margin:-100px 0 0 -100px; /* is width and height divided by two */
    text-align:center;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="preloader">
        <div id="status">
            <h4>Loading...</h4> <!-- include your loading img here -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <h3>This is a body text</h3>
</body>
```